# Dynamic colors css or inline styling asp.net mvc razor

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So This is my div and the for loop creates a new list item and based on the id of the ticket in the database it displays all the states the ticket was in i.e open, In Progress , closed, etc.

```
 <div id="Child" style="display:inline-block;" class="box">
            <ul id="first-list">
                <!--Foreach Goes Here-->
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                <li>
                    <span></span>
                    <div class="title">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Description)
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ActivityContent).</div>
                    <div class="info">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Subject) <a href=@Url.Action("EditActivity", "Home", new { area = "EditActivity", Id = item.TicketId , TypeId = item.ActivityTypeId }) data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" data-modal="edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></div>
                    <div class="name">- @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CreatedByUser)</div>
                    <div class="time">
                        @if(item.ModifiedDateTime != null)
                        {
                            <span>@(item.ModifiedDateTime == null ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(item.ModifiedDateTime).ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"))</span>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <span>@(item.CreatedDateTime == null ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(item.CreatedDateTime).ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"))</span>
                        }
                        @if(item.ModifiedDateTime != null)
                        {
                            <span style="padding-left:35px;">@(item.ModifiedDateTime == null ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(item.ModifiedDateTime).ToShortTimeString())</span>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <span style="padding-left:35px;">@(item.CreatedDateTime == null ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(item.CreatedDateTime).ToShortTimeString())</span>
                        }
                    </div>
                </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
```

What I would like to do is add a different color for each state. such as green when the state is open and red when closed. Anyone have a good way to approach this? I am setting the color for the div in a class called box which looks like this...

```
.box ul li {
            margin: 30px 60px 60px;
            position: relative;
            padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            background: #e56565;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 10px;
            line-height: 20px;
            width: 55%
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this issue.

Comment: Is `State` a property of each item ? How does it's structure looks like ? Are you populating that in the GET Action ?

Comment: I am not sure if State is a property of each item. Yes I am getting it from the get action. The columns are id, ticketId, activityTypeId, ActivityContent, Subject and also the createdDateTime, modifiedDateTime and an OrderDateTime which displays the createddatetime or modifieddatetime based if modified is null and if modified is greater than createddatetime.

Comment: Where do you get state from then ? Each item has a state. Isn't it ?

Comment: Yeah didnt know what you meant by state it comes from the ActivityTypeId which I will use another get action to get the state.

Comment: how are activityTypeId and state are connected ?

Comment: activitytypeid is the foreignkey which connects to my activitytype tables unique Id and state is a column that table

Comment: So Do you have a ActivityType property in your item ? If yes, You do not need to query each activitytype using the activitytypeId. It will be loaded in your GET action itself. But if that is not the case, i would suggest you to read the activitytypes and store it in a dictionary and read from that inside the loop instead of hitting the table in a loop.

Comment: Will do, I have just ran some quick tests and none of them have worked for me. Have you tested this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more maintainable way is to add a new column to your state look up table for the background color or css class. Seed the value with the color you want and read it from the table and use it.

Another option is to create CSS classes which matches with the state name/code/id. and use that. The problem with this approach is, every time you add a new status to the system, you need a code change as well (Adding a new css class). These css classes will be simply to override the bg color. So your code will generate the css class name by using the state code/name/id/.

Something like this.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <li class="li-@(item.State.Code)">
     <!-- Existing code-->
  </li>
}
```

Assuming you have State code values such as open and closed, you will create 2 css classes

```
.li-open
{
  background-color:green;
}
.li-closed
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

These specific css classes should override the default li styles. Use `!important` as needed in your css

Comment: Check the state in the controller first. Set the css classes in the controller before the page is rendered with ViewBag.Color = "green".  Then you have a css class called "green". In the html the tag would look like: <li class= "@ViewBag.Color">

Comment: So you think I should set the color in the Database? Then get it from the db somehow?

Comment: Perfect Answer. Exactly what I was looking for thanks a lot for the quick and  straight to the point answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Dynamic CSS Color

I would opt for using css variables since this allows you to generate new content without needing to change the styles or add new classes. I have no experience with asp.net but this could translate over pretty well.

You pass a css variable to your html as a style property and then use that variable in your css... This is where you need to implement your asp.net to fill in the variable...

*Change the below red to a variable of your choosing, this is just the concept.*

```
<style>
    .myDiv {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        color: var(--textColor);
    }
</style>
<div class="myDiv" style="'--textColor: red;'>Some block</div>
```

From here, you would use Javascript to either change the value of your css variable with the below

```
const root = document.querySelector(':root');
root.style.setProperty('--textColor', 'blue');
```

Or in Vue logic simply dynamically change the value with something like this

```
<div class="myDiv" :style="'--textColor: ' + backgroundVariable + ';'">
    Some Block
</div>
```